# .printout command: why sending printing commands separately for each copy?

Tags: excel, vba, printing

When the code below executes, Excel sends separate printout commands to the printer for each copy instead of sending only one command for all copies.

That problem slows down the print process a lot. How do I speed up by sending less commands to the printer instead of separate commands for each copy?

```
Sub tryPrint()
Dim Barcode As Worksheet
Set Barcode = Sheets("ETIKET")

Application.PrintCommunication = False
With Barcode.PageSetup
   .FitToPagesTall = 1
   .FitToPagesWide = 1
End With
Application.PrintCommunication = True

Barcode.PrintOut , Preview:=False, Copies:=4, ActivePrinter:="\\MUHASEBE\Argox OS-214 plus series PPLA"

End Sub
```

For example: with 4 copies specified, the code sends 4 different commands to the printer:

```
Barcode 1
Barcode 1
Barcode 1
Barcode 1
```

Instead, I would like it to send as in:

```
Barcode 4
```

That way, it would speed up the process by 100%. 
Thanks for any suggestions!

Comment: So, what is `lastrow`, where does it come from? What is `Barcode`? `etiket / ekleTable` seem to be a listObjects, listColumns or PivotTables, how does the data inside look? what is koli?  `Barcode.PrintOut , Prev....` means you are ignoring the first argument of the Function call to `Barrcode.Printout`.... Please try this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example  For all i know, the error happens inside of the `Barcode`, which could be just about anything.

Comment: You are right. I specified my code and my problem as much as possible in the post above. I hope, it is more clear right now. I do not guess it is about what is going on within the spreadsheet.

Comment: Seems to be the default behaviour, there is a workaround here: https://www.ozgrid.com/forum/forum/help-forums/excel-general/10328-printing-multiple-copies I'll see if I can test this and write an answer.

Comment: Looking around, a possible keyword to look out for would be the "Mopier"-Mode. Did you verify that your copier can even receive a command to print multiple copies?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I could not reproduce this, but the solution apparently works:**

Source: [www.papercut.com](https://www.papercut.com/kb/Main/ExcelPrintingIssues)

Setting `Collate:=False` when passing the arguments to `.Printout` should do the trick. You would have to manually sort the copies after this, but since you are printing the same label anyway it makes no difference.

The documentation can be found here: [Excel.Worksheet.PrintOut](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.printout)

Comment: This worked perfect. Never thought it would make the difference. Thank you!